# Better way to deal with is/as checking and casting

Tags: c#

All over in our code we type check things, and then immediately need to cast them. Something like this:

```
if((foo is SomeClass) && (foo as SomeClass).Bar != null) {
    SomeClass fooClass = foo as SomeClass;
    DoSomething(fooClass.Bar);
    ...
}
```

What I wish is that there was some way that, after an explicit type check, references to `foo` could implicitly be converted to the class:

```
if (foo is SomeClass && foo.Bar != null) {
    DoSomething(foo.Bar);
}
```

It passed `(foo is SomeClass)` so we know that `foo` is a `SomeClass`. The `as` cast seems superfluous. If you're inside a statement where you have passed `(foo is SomeClass)` then it seems like you shouldn't have to then explicitly convert `foo` to `SomeClass`

Before anyone says anything about coding practices... I know. Ideally in most places in our application we make good use of generics, abstract classes, interfaces, and all other methods to interact with objects in a reasonable manner. But sometimes you get an `object` and need to check it, especially out of things like events. I don't have a real problem with doing `is`/`as` all over, I was just curious if there was some syntactical magic I could employ that was a bit cleaner. This is an experiment in syntax optimization, not practicality.

As a test, I played with an extension method called I called `IsAs`:

```
public static bool IsAs<T>(this object check, out T result) {
    if (check is T) {
        result = (T)check;
        return true;
    }
    result = default(T);
    return false;
}
```

This returns a bool, fulfilling the `is` portion, and uses a reference input to populate the cast value for the `as`. But in practice, the syntax is not much cleaner:

```
SomeClass fooClass;
if(foo.IsAs<SomeClass>(out fooClass) && fooClass.Bar != null) {
    DoSomething(fooClass)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Look up pattern matching. Modern C# would write this as `if (foo is SomeClass s && s.Bar != null)` or `if (foo is SomeClass { Bar: {} Bar })`

Comment: It is a bad practice to use both 'is' and 'as' on the same thing. You are doing extra work that is not necessary. If you need to access the actual object, use 'as'. If you only need to check if the object is of a specific type (but aren't going to access any members of it) use 'is'. Or, as others have said, use the new pattern matching feature.

Comment: Good implementation, but C# supports that out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using an `is` [type pattern expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#the-is-type-pattern-expression), you can assign the resulting cast to a variable:

```
if (foo is SomeClass fooSomeClass && fooSomeClass.Bar != null) 
{
    DoSomething(fooSomeClass.Bar);
}
```

Comment: It's always nice to find a feature already exists that we hope would :)

Comment: Updating our C# version just got bumped to the top of my TODO list. This is just another thing in the list of changes that can clean up some commonly used things in our code

Comment: Combining pattern matching with the new switch expression in C# 8 is also pretty awesome: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression#patterns-and-case-guards